# Midi in/out for game engine via animation nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

Is there any chance you may add a node for implementing midi signals in a store-ready game engine product made in Blender? :D

Or is this just impossible (and a stupid question)?

Marius

Answer (score 1):

The idea of implementing midi into animation nodes is relatively old:
https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues/332

It might be possible that we have a node for that later but then there is also the problem with the game engine. AN doesn't work with the game engine.

So unfortunally I have to say that this is just impossible.